# Could not find the main class. Program will exit

Tags: java

I made a Java application with netbeans and i made a jar file of it (with Build project button)

The .jar file is running on my pc.I tried to run it on other pc (i have installed java jre)
and i have the error message "Could not find the main class. Program will exit"

my main class is called login.class
I opened the manifest.mf of jar file and it look's ok

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.7.0_02-b13 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar lib/beansbinding-1
 .2.1.jar lib/jcalendar-1.4.1.v201109071408.jar lib/jgoodies-common-1.
 2.0.jar lib/jgoodies-looks-2.4.1.jar lib/junit-4.6.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: login
```

Comment: Try adding a `.` to your classpath in your manifest file.

Comment: do you have lib directory next to jar file containing the required jars?

Comment: @Jigar Joshi: I think in case of missing jars there will be ClassNotFoundException, not issue like this.

Comment: Do you have the main class in a packet? If so change mainclass tag to Main-Class: ThePacket.login. Also, note that class names should start with a captial letter, and it's case sensitive. So make sure your class is really called login and not Login

Comment: thanks all
my main class called login and it is on <default packet> and include in jar file.  how can i writed to mainclass tag

Comment: juergen d 
where will a add  the . 
i have copy all the folder 'dist' to the other pc

Answer (score 2):

(1) Check, if the application starts if you call it from a console:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

If that works (and you tried it with starting the application from an explorer window before), then it is most likely a configuration problem with windows (or whatever OS you use)

(2) inspect your `jar` file with any zip tool - it needs to contain a file `login.class` in the jars root directory.

(3) If you added the last line to your manifest manually: make sure that the manifest file ends with an empty line, otherwise, the last line will not be parsed.

Comment: i try to run to my pc

C:\MyApp2>java -jar MyApp2.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile MyApp2.jar


but whene i double click jar file it runs (to my pc)

to other pc i have the error
Could not find the main class. Program will exit

Comment: The first error puzzles me - it looks as if `MyApp2.jar` is not in the current directory. The other one shows, that we don't have a problem with the jar but with the configuration of the computers: the way, they launch applications, is different.